# How to create a series of text menus in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, menu

I'm writing a small program that prints a menu screen with a list of options. If you choose one of the options, the screen is cleared and you're taken to the next menu.

Right now, I've made a base Menu class and given it a method `draw()` which draws the options. I then want to add a another method `handle_options()` which takes user input and then whisks the user off to the appropriate choice.

At the moment, I am creating a series of subclasses like `class MainMenu(Menu)` and `class OptionsMenu(Menu)`. When `handle_options()` is looping, I'll create an instance of the appropriate Menu class, and draw it, then loop into option choices.

But the thing is, I don't want to have to define this `handle_options()` method for each variant of Menu. So I ask:

a) Is there a design pattern or better way of doing this kind of thing I can learn from?

b) Can I use something like `getattr(self, "myfunc")()` to call a function name I have stored in an array, so I can genericise the `handle_options()` method and define it in the base Menu class, rather than for each subclass?

tl;dr - What kinds of examples or patterns can be used to build a simple text-based menu system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to defining `handle_options` for every subclass of `Menu` is to define a dict that maps an option to a function call:

```
class Menu(object):
   def __init__(self):
      # Ideally, self._options would be an empty dict for the base class.
      # This is just for the sake of example.
      self._options = {'a': self.optionA,
                       'b': self.optionB}

   def handle_options(self, option):
      if option not in self._options:
         print "Invalid option"
         # re-draw
         return

      self._options[option]()

   def optionA(self):
      print "option A"

   def optionB(self):
      print "option B"
```

Now your subclasses simply have to redefine `self._options` and provide the appropriate methods associated with each option:

```
class SubMenu(Menu):
   def __init__(self):
      Menu.__init__(self)

      self._options = {'c': self.optionC,
                       'd': self.optionD}

   def optionC(self):
      # ...

   def optionD(self):
      # ...
```

You can also expand on `self._options` to provide text description, for example, so your draw function can simply iterate through the options printing each one. Take a look at how to use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to infer a good design.

Comment: How could I expand on self._options to provide text description?